# JSON.encode is adding backslashes

Tags: php, json

Had to re do this as last question was marked to close as duplicate. BUT the "Duplicate" question was about json decoding not encoding and adding to a file. I have also stated in my question the things I have tried, which as it so happens was the accepted answer on the 'duplicate'.

Please do not mark as duplicate again without actually checking it is.

When I try to create a file with some generated JSON data, the result is like so:

```
 "{\"1\":{\"title\":\"Sidemen: The Book\",\"ISBN\":\"1473648165\"
```

as you can see, it has wrapped everything in **"" quotes ""**

It has also added in lots of:  **' \ '** which I don't want.

This is what I currently have:

```
$json = json_encode($BookList);
```

and I create the file in PHP like so:

```
$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
fclose($fp);
```

I have tried:

```
$json = json_encode($BookList, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

and:

```
$json = json_encode($BookList, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$json_edited = stripslashes($json);
```

but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

Update

Book list is generated like so:

```
$BookList[++$id] = [
    'title'  => (string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title,
    'ISBN'   => '' .(string) $item->ItemAttributes->ISBN
];
```

Comment: You probably are seeing the result of PHP escaping those quotes in a `var_export` it probably doesn't have those slashes in the actual string content.

Comment: Roger that @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 5):

You're double-encoding your data, e.g., passing it through `json_encode` twice. You have

```
$json = json_encode($BookList, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
// -----^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and also

```
fwrite($fp, json_encode($json));
// ---------^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You only want **one** of those.

Comment: Legend, that fixed it. Thank you.